# mkdir permission denied in shell script

Tags: shell

I've seen similar questions to this all over the internet, but I haven't been able to find one quite the same as what I'm running into.  Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've been trying to find an answer for about an hour before asking this question...

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter path:"
read path
echo "Enter title:"
read title
mkdir -pv "${path}/${title}"
```

In/Out:

```
Enter path:
~/test
Enter title:
testing
mkdir: cannot create directory '/testing': Permission denied
```

Whereas, if I run

```
mkdir -pv ~/test/testing
```

whether from the terminal or hard-coded into the script, then it works without any issues.

I've also tried using /bin/mkdir, removing the -p, removing the {} or "" around the mkdir call, etc. but I can't get it to work.  Also, the script has all permissions (-rwxrwxrwx).

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Try to enter the real path of your home directory instead of the tllde shortcut because, from the error, your path variable is null. That said, should not use variable name that are the same as standard environment variable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, problem is `~/test`, the `~` is not getting expanded. So, if you will check again, you will find a `~` directory in the current-directory where you executed the script.

Here is an example where you expand `~` using `eval`:

```
$ cat dirtest.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter path: "
read my_dir
eval my_dir="$my_dir"
echo "Enter title: "
read title
mkdir -pv "${my_dir}/$title"
```

Comment: Thank you!  You nailed it!  It looks like I can either use "eval" like you mentioned or the user would need to input "/home/username/..." as the path instead of just "~/".  Using eval seems like the safer option.  Thanks again!

Comment: Good. I didn't suggest using `$HOME` here because I understand that you are looking for some user input. In that case, you have to tell the user to never use `~/` and always use `$HOME/`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `mkdir: cannot create directory '/testing': Permission denied` that the lookup of ~/test didn't work, so you are actually trying to create `/testing` in your drive root directory , which you can't as a regular user.

I don't know a workaround for that ~ shorthand in a bash variable, so either type the full path, or search for something like a workaround for that.